# ubuntu spurious environment variable

Tags: 12.04, gnome, environment-variables

I have a spurious path in my ~PATH~ environment variable in `Ubuntu`:

`/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm`

I have no idea where it is set. I have checked these files:

```
/etc/environment
/etc/profile
/etc/profile.d/*
/etc/bash.bashrc
~/.bash_profile
~/.bashrc
~/.profile
~/.pam_environment
```

Any idea where else it can be or how can I find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot find out, where it is set, i is not in /etc/skel, too, nowhere in /etc and nowhere in /home/. But I found out, why it is [set](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/868363). I also started bash with -x to see, what happens, but the only thing I can see there is

```
complete -F _service /etc/init.d/lightdm
```

and I cannot find references to PATH or set there (No wonder, the initscript has been converted to an upstart job). But, to calm you, this is default behaviour in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Notably missing from the list is `~/.bash_profile`. I recommend checking there (if you have not done so).

This file doesn't always exist, and it's not a problem when it doesn't. However, if it *does* exist, it is executed by initial login shells *instead of* `.profile`. (So if it doesn't itself run or `source` `.profile`, `.profile` will not run at all.)

That's just in `bash` of course. `.bash_profile` is ignored by other shells--it's a good place to put commands that are `bash`-specific (so long as you make sure to source `.profile` in it if there's code there that needs running).

For more information on startup scripts, see [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/bash.1.html).

Comment: I don't have this file at all

Comment: @rowman In that case, that's not it. (Edited to generalize for others.)